# Bulk insert data using recordset and return new ID's quickly

Tags: asp-classic, ado, adodb, recordset

How can I bulk insert a number of records and obtain the last inserted ID of each quickly (classic asp/ado)?

I have tried this but it only runs at about 3 rows per second which is a joke.

```
rs.Open "myTable", cn,adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
do while NOT rs.EOF   
    rs.AddNew        
    rs("text") = myFunction() ' returns some text.
    rs.update
    lastid = rs("id") ' get new id and so something
loop
```

Using the normal adOpenForwardOnly (which doesn't return the last inserted ID) it runs about 1000x faster.

Can anyone suggest either a fix to the above or an alternative solution? I have to do this in the code rather than straight sql insert into ... select() etc. because I need to run a processing function on the text.

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: I don't think is yet enough info in your question to answer it properly.  How many rows are we typically talking about?  Why is it necessary to retrieve the IDs then and there instead of later?  The code looks "psuedo" to me can you flesh it out make it more real currently its an infinite loop?  How does the input driving data related to created rows, where does the input data come from?  What is so unique about `myFunction` that the same function cannot be replicated in T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this quickly is to use a bulk-insert in a stored procedure. You end up running a query to get back all the IDs but it reduces the main bottleneck: the number of trips to the database.

Comment: How does the "bulk-insert in a stored procedure" call the `myFunction` method defined in VBScript?

Comment: Personally, I'd write it out to a CSV file first and import the CSV.

Comment: How would using a CSV file get a list of the ID's?  Also as someone has pointed out the myFunction cannot be replicated in SQL in this case.